# Defining and Using Extension Methods

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I have a `Dictionary(Of IPAddress, MyClass)` called `Me.clients`, and I would like to remove certain entries from this dictionary. Previously, the dictionary was `Of IpAddress, Date` and the following code worked fine:

```
For Each entry in Me.clients.Where(Function(kv) Me.isInactive(kv.Key).ToArray()    
  Me.clients.Remove(entry.Key)
Next
```

After I changed the Value type of the dictionary to a custom class (`MyClass`), I now get the error

> Public member 'Where' on type 'Dictionary(Of IPAddress, MyClass)' not found.

Does the extension method `Where()` work only when the Dictionary's Key/Value types are built-in? How can I define the extension method so that it works with my `Dictionary(Of IPAddress, MyClass)`. If I have dictionaries `Of IPAddress, MyClass` *and* `Of IPAddress, MyOtherClass`, do I need to define `Where()` extensions for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the declaration of clients from this:

```
Private clients = New Dictionary(Of IPAddress, Client)
```

To this:

```
Private clients As New Dictionary(Of IPAddress, Client)
```

---

In the former, it's really the same as:

```
Private clients As Object = New Dictionary(Of IPAddress, Client)
```

Which could have a Where, if you cast it to something enumerable, but that's a drag…

```
DirectCast(clients, Dictionary(Of IPAddress, Client)).Where(...)
```

It's just inside an object, so it looks like an object (and option infer doesn't)..

Comment: Thank you very much! This partially answers the question that I posed in my comment to your other answer. I'm still somewhat confused though. Is this some sort of polymorphism thing going on? What exactly is the difference between `Dim foo = New Dictionary(Of...)` vs `Dim foo As Dictionary(Of...) = New Dictionary(Of...)`?

Comment: If you're Dimming in a method(function or sub) with Option Infer On the compiler will work out the type of the variable for you; it doesn't do that with properties. Properties need an As to declare the type

Comment: @SeanEricson, you should turn `Option Strict On` and then the first code snippet would not compile. ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` unless you explicitly require late-binding, which is fairly rare. Turn it `On` in the project properties and also in the VS options, so it is `On` by default for all future projects.